# What is the correct way to reference time zones in relation to an event?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

When referring to the time of a particular event, should I refer to the local time or the time zone most relevant to the audience or always include reference to the time zone? It can be further complicated when having to specify Standard or Daylight Saving times.  It seems that you would have to reference all times as Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) to avoid having to list multiple times.

Comment: What type of work is this? A book, essay, etc.?

Comment: It is actually in regards to listings of college football games on a website.  Most of the teams listed (and presumably their fan bases) are in Central time Zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick look at two well known newspapers in the US, the Chicago Tribune and the New York Times. When reporting events, neither included specifications for time zone--local time was assumed or explicitly stated ("at 3 p.m. local time, German chancellor..."). The exception was for sporting events, where the phrase "all times listed are EST [or CST]" appeared.

With fiction, I just use local time and extrapolate as needed.

Using Greenwich Mean Time seems like a good idea in a situation where characters are frequently switching time zones, such as in an aviation story or drama, but I would guess that fewer than 10% of Americans would understand the expression.

Comment: I think GMT is pretty foreign to a lot of Americans, but some who don't know GMT may recognize "Zulu Time" instead. Additionally, In the course of making sure I got Zulu Time right I found out GMT is now obsolete, and is currently referred to as UTC. I think I'll stick with Zulu Time.